# Interfaces for writing and reading Strings

Tags: java

I'm currently using `java.io.PrintStream`'s:

```
public void print(String s)
```

to print to the standard output. I also use my own class which has a:

```
public void read(String expectedResponse) throws IOException
```

method for reading over a ssh connection.

I now wish to use dispatching so that I can add a Logger class which implements both the read and write methods, for the sake of logging what is being sent and read to a single file. What interface classes can I use which declare the print and read methods?

I really don't understand why there is interfaces for Appendable, Closeable, Flushable, but no Printable interface.

Comment: Don't use PrintStream. It's obsolete. Its javadoc says: *The PrintWriter class should be used in situations that require writing characters rather than bytes.*

Comment: `public void read(String expectedResponse)`: This method signature doesn't make any sense. What is it supposed to do with the argument, and where is it supposed to put the result of the read?

Comment: @EJP I'm writing a Test Framework so its actually the expected response read from a certain interface in response to what is written to it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'declare the print and read methods', I would suggest that you look at the [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org) logging façade. This is one of the de-facto logging solutions used out in the wild, and it's worth looking at a meaningful solution once you head down the logging path. Have fun!